# Как в массиве поменять два элемента местами?

Tags: php, массивы, функции, foreach, arraylist

Как в коде меняют местами "firstname"("Martin") и имя массива ("Krönström"), а точнее как в первом цикле foreach присвоив значение `$firstname = $lastnames[$key]['firstname'];`, используют его в `$newlastnames[$firstname]["firstname"] = $key;`?

Поясните, пожалуйста, что, куда присваивается в `funcion a`?

```
function a ($lastnames){
    $newlastnames;
    foreach($lastnames as $key => $value){
        $firstname = $lastnames[$key]['firstname'];
        $newlastnames[$firstname]["firstname"] = $key;
        $newlastnames[$firstname]["age"] = $lastnames[$key]['age'];
        $newlastnames[$firstname]["sex"] = $lastnames[$key]['sex'];
        echo $lastnames[$key]['firstname'].'<br>';
   }
    return $newlastnames;
}
```

Целый код тут

```
$lastnames = array(

"Krönström" => array("firstname" => "Martin",     "age" => 20, "sex" => "male"),
"Kulper"    => array("firstname" => "Laura-Liis", "age" => 17, "sex" => "female"),
"Ööbik"     => array("firstname" => "Tõnis",      "age" => 21, "sex" => "male"),

"Mitri"   => array("firstname" => "Martten", "age" => 35, "sex" => "male"),
"Lõsenko" => array("firstname" => "Evelina", "age" => 16, "sex" => "female"),
"Reinaus" => array("firstname" => "Richard", "age" => 21, "sex" => "male"));

$newlastnames =  a($lastnames);
saveFile($newlastnames);

function saveFile($lastnames){
    file_put_contents("q.json",json_encode($lastnames));
}


function a ($lastnames){
    $newlastnames;
    foreach($lastnames as $key => $value){
        $firstname = $lastnames[$key]['firstname'];
        $newlastnames[$firstname]["firstname"] = $key;
        $newlastnames[$firstname]["age"] = $lastnames[$key]['age'];
        $newlastnames[$firstname]["sex"] = $lastnames[$key]['sex'];
        echo $lastnames[$key]['firstname'].'<br>';
   }
    return $newlastnames;
}
function sortA($lastnames,$sortValue){
    foreach($lastnames as $key => $value){
        if($sortValue == "firstname"){
            $throwArray[$key] = $key;
        }else{
            $throwArray[$key] = $value[$sortValue];
        }
    }
    array_multisort($throwArray, SORT_DEC, $lastnames);
    return $lastnames;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поясните, что именно непонятного?

1. В функцию мы передаем массив, где ключ это фамилия, а значение - массив с данными о пользователе
2. Создаем новый массив $newlastnames
3. Начинаем перебирать в цикле переданный в функцию массив.
4. `$firstname` мы присваиваем имя пользователя.
5. Затем начинаем забивать данные в наш новый массив `$newlastnames`, используя имя `$firstname` в качестве ключа, а в значение его мы кидаем данные из полей `firstname`, `age`, `sex`.

Comment: $firstname = $lastnames[$key]['firstname'];                            я так понял что в $firstname передается значение  "Martin" из массива  "Krönström" и   $newlastnames[$firstname]["firstname"] = $key;  в  $newlastnames записывается под ключом "Martin" и в  'firstname'   записывается значение $key "Krönström"

Comment: совершенно верно